# How to call a web service from data layer

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, sharepoint-2003

I have a data layer project which receives a byte array that needs to be persisted.  The byte array will be stored in Sharepoint 2003, so I'd like to be able to call a SP web service from within the data layer (keeping all persistence in this layer).

Here's the approach I am considering, if there are any comments on it. 
http://blogs.msdn.com/erikaehrli/archive/2006/05/04/SharePointUploadHelper.aspx

My question is, Is it possible to add a web service (not WCF) reference to a non-web project?  I don't see the option in Visual Studio.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After looking further, it appears that you can add a "service reference", then click the "advanced" tab, where you can then add a web service reference.

Answer (score 1):

Jeremy, just saw your correct answer. For screen shots see:

http://carlosfemmer.com/post/2008/01/How-to-add-web-reference-in-VS-2008-Project.aspx